# Print all keys from a dictionary in the format of key1.key2.key3

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key

Here is my dictionary (or JSON)

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
    "name": "Product",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "number",
            "description": "Product identifier",
            "required": True
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Name of the product",
            "required": True
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0,
            "required": True
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "stock": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "warehouse": {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "retail": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I want to print all keys with this format `key1.key2.key3`. This is my code:

```
def myprint(d, keys = ''):
    for k, v in d.items():
        temp = keys
        keys += k
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            keys += '.'
            myprint(v,keys)
        else:
            print(keys)
            keys = temp
```

Unfortunately, this failed where returns result like this:

```
$schema
type
name
properties.stock.type
properties.stock.properties.warehouse.type
properties.stock.properties.warehouse.retail.type
properties.stock.price.minimum
properties.stock.price.type
properties.stock.price.required
properties.stock.price.tags.items.type
properties.stock.price.tags.items.type
properties.stock.price.tags.id.required
properties.stock.price.tags.id.type
properties.stock.price.tags.id.description
properties.stock.price.tags.id.name.required
properties.stock.price.tags.id.name.type
properties.stock.price.tags.id.name.description
```

As you see, the last several lines are wrong.

Anyone have suggestions? Not only restrict from this script other methods are welcome, but no module being used.

Comment: What do you mean by "no module being used"?

Comment: @wim Like no import collection(or other module)

Comment: `collections` is built-in with any Python installation.  So, why can't you use it?

Comment: @wim: because this is probably homework

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem homework? I never recieved h/w of this level without the use of import modules. Odd?

Comment: @SurajKothari: well I do not think this is JSON, it is simpy a Python dictionary, and this is simple recursion.

Comment: It's json, because look at the booleans.  But Eleanor must have parsed it before calling `myprint`.

Comment: By the way, isn't anyone going to answer the post? I am no expert here and don't want to post a bad answer.

Comment: I don't answer questions with arbitrary restrictions, so I'm still waiting on the answer to why other modules can't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you make it complicated by updating `keys`. A string in Python is *immutable*. We can each time pass an extended key to the next recursive level, so with:

```
def myprint(d, keys = ''):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            myprint(v, '{}{}.'.format(keys, k))
        else:
            print('{}{}'.format(keys, k))
```

This then yields:

```
>>> myprint(d)
$schema
name
type
properties.id.type
properties.id.description
properties.id.required
properties.name.type
properties.name.description
properties.name.required
properties.price.type
properties.price.minimum
properties.price.required
properties.tags.type
properties.tags.items.type
properties.stock.type
properties.stock.properties.warehouse.type
properties.stock.properties.retail.type
```

The problem with your code was that you only restored the old `keys` value in case something was *not* a dictionary. So as a result if there were multiply subdictionaries, you started to concatenate the keys together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
d = {'$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#', 'name': 'Product', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'id': {'type': 'number', 'description': 'Product identifier', 'required': True}, 'name': {'type': 'string', 'description': 'Name of the product', 'required': True}, 'price': {'type': 'number', 'minimum': 0, 'required': True}, 'tags': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'string'}}, 'stock': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'warehouse': {'type': 'number'}, 'retail': {'type': 'number'}}}}}
def display_keys(s, last=None):
   for a, b in s.items():
      if not isinstance(b, dict):
          yield "{}.{}".format(last, a) if last else str(a)
      else:
         for h in display_keys(b, str(a) if not last else '{}.{}'.format(last, a)):
           yield h

 print(list(display_keys(d)))
```

Output:

```
['$schema', 'name', 'type', 'properties.id.type', 'properties.id.description', 'properties.id.required', 'properties.name.type', 'properties.name.description', 'properties.name.required', 'properties.price.type', 'properties.price.minimum', 'properties.price.required', 'properties.tags.type', 'properties.tags.items.type', 'properties.stock.type', 'properties.stock.properties.warehouse.type', 'properties.stock.properties.retail.type']
```